# Variable "entrySlug" does not exist Routing

Tags: templating, routes, routing

I currently have a routing set up as follows to enable an "Edit" entry page following on from [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28565/edit-entry-page/28571#28571) but I'm getting the following error message when going to that page.

> Variable "entrySlug" does not exist

I have my routing set up as follows within my CP, which loads a URL like so `mydomain.com/marketplace/authorname/entryname/edit`

[image]

and within my `listings/_edit`

```
{# Find the entry by slug and author: #}
{% set listing = craft.entries({
    section: 'networks',
    slug: entrySlug,
    author: currentUser
}).one() %}
```

I'm really unsure why it can't find the slug of the entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I don't think setting up the route via the CP does the fancy advanced rule stuff described [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules). You'll therefore want to do that via the `config/routes.php` file with something like this:

```
'marketplace/<authorSlug:[^\/]+>/<entrySlug:{slug}>/edit' => ['template' => 'listings/_edit'],
```

Now `authorSlug` and `entrySlug` will be available for use in your `listings/_edit.twig` template...